# Deploying my React app with react i18n throws a 404 error on locales.json

Tags: reactjs, netlify, react-i18next

I've deployed my React app (CRA) on Netlify but it gives me 404 error on all the translations.json files. It's working locally so I'm lost.

My i18n settings file looks like this:

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend'
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'

export const appLocales = ['en', 'ja', 'nl']

i18n.use(Backend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        debug: false,
        lng: 'en',
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        whitelist: appLocales,
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false
        }
    })

export default i18n
```

Although the translations seems to be working I'm wondering why it's throwing the 404 error in the first place. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Where in your source tree do you have your translation files? If they are in `public`, then `npm build` should include them in the `build` directory. Check out [i18n-react-app](https://github.com/mogsdad/i18n-react-app) for an example based on the Create React App starting point.